Algorithm to compute the canonical form of a (skew-)symmetric matrix pencil
Let $A, B$ be $2n \times 2n$ complex skew-symmetric matrices. There exists a canonical form for the pencil $A - \lambda B$, related to the Kronecker canonical form (which itself is a generalization of Jordan normal form to pencils), which explicitly incorporates the skew-symmetry of the matrices. This was given by Thompson in 1991 and states that, borrowing modern notation from Dmytryshyn & Dopico, the pencil $A - \lambda B$ can be block-diagonalized where each block is one of three types:
$$\begin{align}
H(\mu) &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & J_k(\mu)\\
-J_k(\mu)^T & 0
\end{bmatrix} - \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_k\\
-I_k & 0
\end{bmatrix},\\
K &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_k\\
-I_k & 0
\end{bmatrix} - \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
0 & J_k(0)\\
-J_k(0)^T & 0
\end{bmatrix},\\
M &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & F_k\\
-F_k^T & 0
\end{bmatrix} - \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
0 & G_k\\
-G_k^T & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}$$
where $I_k$ is the $k \times k$ identity matrix, $J_k(\mu)$ is the $k \times k$ Jordan matrix with $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$ on the diagonals, and $F_k$ and $G_k$ are $k \times (k+1)$ matrices defined as
$$\begin{align}
F_k &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_k
\end{bmatrix}, \quad G_k = \begin{bmatrix}
I_k & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
Each block does not necessarily have the same size $k$.
Like the KCF, we can immediately read off the singularities ($M$), the infinite eigenvalues ($K$), and the finite eigenvalues ($H(\mu)$) from this decomposition. However, it has the nice property that, because of skew-symmetry, we only need to read the top-right block of each block to get the generalized eigenvalues (and then double the occurrences to get multiplicities, if desired). This may be preferrable to the KCF, and moreover would likely roughly halve the computational effort (similar to how eigensolvers for Hermitian matrices achieve their savings).
Is there any established numerical algorithm for computing this decomposition? One that is numerically stable and costs at most $O(n^3)$ time would be ideal - but I have yet to encounter any record of such an algorithm, stable or otherwise. And if so, are there any publicly available codes to actually implement it?
Note that similar forms exist when either $A$ and/or $B$ are instead symmetric (see Thompson again). Such instances are not of my immediate interest but are sufficiently related that any leads in those cases would be appreciated as well.

I don't work exactly in this field, but I'll try an explanation based on what I understand of it. I'll use the Jordan form as an example because it is simpler, but everything I write also applies to Kronecker-like canonical forms.
Questions like this one are tricky to address numerically because they rely on rank decisions: for instance, does the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2/9 & -1/9\\
4/9 & -2/9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
have a nontrivial Jordan block or not? In exact arithmetic yes, but this question is ill-posed: make an arbitrarily small modification to one entry, and the answer becomes no. In particular once you replace the matrix entries with their floating-point approximations, the answer is no. In machine arithmetic, the computations you make to decide whether there is a double eigenvalue will return not $0$, but a number of the order of $10^{-16}$. Any numerical software will have to rely on an arbitrary threshold to decide what the Jordan form of $A$ is.
So it is more useful to ask a different question: what is the distance between the given $A$ and the nearest matrix with a nontrivial Jordan block? This distance is a continuous function of $A$, it can be computed numerically, and it returns useful information even if the answer is $10^{-16}$. We might learn that a certain matrix is at distance $10^{-16}$ from one with a Jordan block of size 2, and at distance $10^{-14}$ from one with a Jordan block of size 3; this information is more useful than a straight yes or no, or a single Jordan decomposition.
This is related to so-called "stratification", i.e., the study of how different Jordan structures can be perturbed into one another. For instance, an arbitrarily small perturbation may turn a matrix with a Jordan block of size 4 (the "least generic" case) into one with two blocks of sizes (3,1) or (2,2), which in turn may become (2,1,1) with a further perturbation, and then the "generic" (1,1,1,1), with distinct eigenvalues and four blocks of size 1. These relations define a directed graph among Jordan structures: an edge tells you that that one structure one "more general" than the other.
There is a Matlab toolbox to compute the distances between your matrix and the closest matrix with a prescribed structure, the MCS toolbox. This software works for many cases, including not only Jordan forms but also the structured Kronecker forms of skew-symmetric pencils.
For a comparison with a more familiar problem that relies on a rank decision, think about computing the rank of a matrix: this is an ill-posed question, but rather than the plain number it is more useful to have the distance between $A$ and the nearest matrix of rank $k$ for each $k=1,2,\dots,n$, and this is precisely what the SVD tells you.

This is really excellent, thank you. The MCS toolbox looks particularly promising.

I had one remaining question though. Perhaps this is just my general ignorance about the Jordan canonical form. While I understand that computing the forms is numerically unstable, if we are merely interested in determining the eigenvalues up to some precision, should one expect the JCF/KCF to still be sufficient for this purpose? (I know that algorithms such as QZ are the standard approach, but I am interested in directly incorporating the skew-symmetry of the problem.)

These kinds of structures usually imply some pairing of the eigenvalues; I'm not sure which one it is for skewsym / skewsym, but from your blocks I think it's even multiplicities, am I correct? In any case, computing eigenvalues with these kinds of constraints in a stable way is usually very tricky numerically; the algorithms have to be implemented in a structure-preserving way from the start and that's quite tricky, there isn't much ready off-the-shelf numerical software available.

I don't know if the MCS toolbox contains structure-preserving algorithms, but my best guess is no; I would also be interested if it did. In general going for a JCF/KCF rather than just computing the eigenvalues is not going to help, unless the algorithm was structure-preserving in the first place: typically to compute a JCF/KCF one first has to compute the eigenvalues, and then make additional transformations.

I see. Yes, for skew-symmetric pencils there is always an even multiplicity (one way to see this is by connecting to the Pfaffian). It seems there is an algorithm for computing "generalized upper triangular" forms (GUPTRI) provided in the MCS but getting such forms to preserve specific structures seems unclear.
